# How To Configure the File Drop Automation Type using Soap APi

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

[image]How To Configure the (File Drop) Automation Type using Soap APi in Automation Studio  this is my code  File Drop is draging but not configured

```
  <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401- 
     wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <UsernameToken>
        <Username>******</Username>
      <Password>*******</Password>
     </UsernameToken>
     </Security>
       </Header>
      <Body>
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <Options/>
        <Objects xsi:type="Automation">
        <Client>
          <ID>7308565</ID>
       </Client>
       <Name>importactivity1</Name>
       <Description>importactivit1y</Description>
      <AutomationTasks>
          <AutomationTask>
             <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
             <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
             <Name>Task</Name>
             <Activities>
                <Activity>
                <ObjectID>0a6d8431-246a-e811-a2ca-1402ec938e99</ObjectID>


                  <Name>Import</Name>
                    <ActivityObject xsi:type="ImportDefinition">

                <CustomerKey>Import_To_DE_Market2Lead_Key</CustomerKey>
               <ObjectID>0a6d8431-246a-e811-a2ca-1402ec938e99</ObjectID>


                     <Name>TestDE</Name>
                      </ActivityObject>
                      </Activity>
                      </Activities>
                      </AutomationTask>             
                  </AutomationTasks>
              <AutomationType>triggered</AutomationType>
         </Objects>
     </CreateRequest>
     </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

**NEW ANSWER**

I have found a better way to accomplish this all in a single call by utilizing REST API.

You use the endpoint `automation/v1/automations` to create (POST) your new automation.

See below example:

```
POST /automation/v1/automations
Host: {{yourSubDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
```

and then the payload:

```
{
    "name": "testRestAuto",
    "description": "testRestAuto",
    "key": "testRestAuto",
    "steps": [
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 0,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "yourActivityID",
                    "name": "yourActivityName",
                    "objectTypeId": 43, 
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "activityObjectId": "{{yourActivityObjectID}}"
                }
            ],
            "id": "f4518041-5702-4712-a690-abc17e6a30f1"
        },
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 1,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "1 Hours",
                    "objectTypeId": 467,
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "activityObjectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "serializedObject": "{\"duration\":1,\"durationUnits\":\"Hours\"}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "startSource": {
        "typeId": 2, /* sets it to Triggered Auto */
        "fileDrop": {
            "filenamePatternTypeId": 0, 
            /* 0 is no name, 1 Contains, 2 begins with, 3 ends with */
            "filenamePattern": "file", 
            /* only used with 1-3 to set string for filename - remove for 0 */
            "folderLocation": "triggered_automations",
            "statusId": 0,
            "queueFiles": true
        }
    },
    "categoryId": 58142 /* Folder ID */
}
```

The important part to pay attention to is the 'startSource' section:

```
    "startSource": {
        "typeId": 2, /* sets it to Triggered Auto */
        "fileDrop": {
            "filenamePatternTypeId": 0, 
            /* 0 is no name, 1 Contains, 2 begins with, 3 ends with */
            "filenamePattern": "file", 
            /* only used with 1-3 to set string for filename - remove for 0 */
            "folderLocation": "triggered_automations",
            "statusId": 0,
            "queueFiles": true
        }
    }
```

This is where you will set up the triggered Send information.

After you created it, you can then use PATCH or GET (utilizing the ObjectID at the end of the endpoint) to update or retrieve your automation.

---

**ORIGINAL RESPONE**

I believe you would need to set Automation Type to "FileTrigger" in your create call and then in a separate call, use the ["FileTrigger" Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/filetrigger.htm) to set up the specifics for your new automation.

[image]

Comment: my question is how to configure the File Drop using Soap Api i mentioned above image check it

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you will need to do this via a separate call to the FileTrigger Object.

Comment: @ Gortonington can you please provide any API do have for File Trigger Object