# How to Setup an File Drop Trigger for an Automation via the API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger, api, automationstudio, automation

I created an automation triggered by a file drop in SFMC using the API but the file drop section still needs to be configured. The closest thing to an answer I could find was [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220807/how-to-configure-the-file-drop-automation-type-using-soap-api) in which someone discusses using a "FileTrigger" Object in a new API Call, but doesn't explain what type of call to use or any other details.

If anyone has any insight I would be so grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a better way to accomplish this all in a single call by utilizing REST API.

You use the endpoint `automation/v1/automations` to create (POST) your new automation.

See below example:

```
POST /automation/v1/automations
Host: {{yourSubDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Authorization: Bearer XXXXXXX
Content-Type: application/json
```

and then the payload:

```
{
    "name": "testRestAuto",
    "description": "testRestAuto",
    "key": "testRestAuto",
    "steps": [
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 0,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "id": "yourActivityID",
                    "name": "yourActivityName",
                    "objectTypeId": 43, 
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "activityObjectId": "{{yourActivityObjectID}}"
                }
            ],
            "id": "f4518041-5702-4712-a690-abc17e6a30f1"
        },
        {
            "annotation": "",
            "stepNumber": 1,
            "activities": [
                {
                    "name": "1 Hours",
                    "objectTypeId": 467,
                    "displayOrder": 0,
                    "activityObjectId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "serializedObject": "{\"duration\":1,\"durationUnits\":\"Hours\"}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "startSource": {
        "typeId": 2, /* sets it to Triggered Auto */
        "fileDrop": {
            "filenamePatternTypeId": 0, 
            /* 0 is no name, 1 Contains, 2 begins with, 3 ends with */
            "filenamePattern": "file", 
            /* only used with 1-3 to set string for filename - remove for 0 */
            "folderLocation": "triggered_automations",
            "statusId": 0,
            "queueFiles": true
        }
    },
    "categoryId": 58142 /* Folder ID */
}
```

The important part to pay attention to is the 'startSource' section:

```
    "startSource": {
        "typeId": 2, /* sets it to Triggered Auto */
        "fileDrop": {
            "filenamePatternTypeId": 0, 
            /* 0 is no name, 1 Contains, 2 begins with, 3 ends with */
            "filenamePattern": "file", 
            /* only used with 1-3 to set string for filename - remove for 0 */
            "folderLocation": "triggered_automations",
            "statusId": 0,
            "queueFiles": true
        }
    }
```

This is where you will set up the triggered Send information.

After you created it, you can then use PATCH or GET (utilizing the ObjectID at the end of the endpoint) to update or retrieve your automation.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your timely and informative answer, it helped me out so much, it is working great now!

For those reading this who have the same question this post was also helpful in solving the problem: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260550/create-or-update-automation-with-marketing-cloud-rest-api-new-endpoint

Comment: @Brett - Great to hear! If this answers your question, please select the checkmark next to the answer to denote this is the correct answer. This will help others in the community to find the answer quicker if they experience the same issue.

Comment: do you if the automation can be activated in the same call?

Comment: I haven't seen a way to activate it in the same call, I believe it may need to be a separate one - but as it is an undocumented Endpoint, there could be something I am missing that will let you do that.

Comment: did you ever discover a way to activate file drop automations through the API using either SOAP or REST?

Comment: Nothing yet. Been asking and mostly getting blank stares in response.

Answer (score 0):

**Activation:**
Just capture it in your browser, the frontend uses:

> POST /legacy/v1/beta/automations/filetrigger/

```
{"publish":true,"fileTriggerProgramId":"--ID--"}
```

But the ID is GUID not UUID so you need to use a diffent endpoint to get the automations then the previous comment suggests

> GET /legacy/v1/beta/automations/automation/definition/?$top=25&$skip=0&$sort=lastRunTime desc&view=gridView